# Cannot find SPICE models of audio transistors for LTSpice?

Tags: components, ltspice

I need to simulate a circuit with the following transistors:

MPS8050 OR MPS6560

AND

MPS8550 OR MPS6562

But I cannot find any for LTSpice.
http://ltwiki.org/ also doesn't have.

TINA has these components but I don't want to pay.

How can I find these or equivalents for LTspice?

Comment: Are you able to find the spice models by searching google?

Comment: i tried but no luck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be sure, I'd have to see the schematic of the circuit you're using these transistors in but I am 99% sure that you can replace any of these transistors with any other general purpose NPN or PNP transistor for which there are models available.

These transistors are Bipolar Junction Transistors or BJTs and these have the nice property that their properties are mainly determined by physics instead of how they're made. They would all operate at Vbe = 0.6 to 0.7 V for example. Other important parameters are the current gain beta (Hfe) and the maximum collector current Ic.

So for the MPS8050, beta = 300 and Ic,max = 1A
No have a look at the transistors for which there **are** LTSpice models and check what their beta and Ic,max are. These don't have to match exactly, a beta between 200 - 500 and Ic,max of more than 0.5A would be OK.

Since you're just using them in a simulator you cannot blow up the transistor when Ic becomes too large, the transistor breaking down is not modeled !

Also, a **proper** design does not rely very much on transistor properties as Vbe and beta as these can **vary a lot** and not only when the temperature changes. To reverse this, if the circuit you simulate would **only** work properly with the transistors you mention, I think it is a **very bad** design.

Since you're using this for audio, this is very low frequency so almost **any** transistor is fast enough.

Comment: thanks just i really dont get why its so hard to make a large database for each transistor for SPICE programs. eachtime i have to spend hours. we re in 2016.

Comment: Well making all those models costs money and transistors must be cheap. And like I said, it does not matter so much which transistor model you use if the circuit is designed properly. If you have to spend hours finding the right model you're doing something wrong. Try spending an hour trying different models in a circuit that you know works well. Do you see much performance difference ? If not: see, it does not matter much.

Comment: there is a circuit already built(not my design). i have to use the components on it. and at the moment i dont know how i can learn to select equivalents:( i know LTspice to use but when a part is missing im screwed...

Comment: You still assume one transistor or the other will make a lot of difference, I'm telling you: **It doesn't**. How to select an equivalent: I explained that in my answer. You could also search for a similar transistor on farnell, digikey but then there is still a chance there's no model for it. So just limit yourself to the transistors that **do** have models. Why do you think there are so few models ? Because experienced engineers only need a few BJT models. The performance comes from the circuit design, not the transistors.

Comment: @user16307 this is good advice generally (+1). If a transistor has a Hfe of 200 it's unlikely that is employed in a circuit that wouldn't work with a Hfe of 50. Try and find an equivalent that has about the same Hfe and also a decent cut-off frequency (Ft) of about the same.

Answer (score 1):

I did a search at the [AllTransistors](http://alltransistors.com/) cross-reference site, which gave me this set of [results](http://alltransistors.com/crsearch.php?mat=Si&struct=NPN&pc=0.625&ucb=40&uce=25&ueb=6&ic=1.5&tj=150&ft=190&cc=9&hfe=85&caps=TO92) for the MPS8050.

It looks things up by taking the transistor parameters and seeing what matches those (really useful if you can't get just the part you would like).

Results for [MPS8550](http://alltransistors.com/crsearch.php?mat=Si&struct=PNP&pc=0.625&ucb=40&uce=25&ueb=6&ic=1.5&tj=150&ft=200&cc=15&hfe=85&caps=TO92)

I realise these are used as complementary pairs, but for the purposes of simulation, at least some of these suggested replacements should have SPICE models available and should give you reasonable simulation results.

The result pages above list equivalent (ish) devices.

In this particular case, you have general purpose audio devices and most such devices would give meaningful results, such as the venerable BC107 and the complement BC177 (both of which have spice models widely available).

If you want to see Beta effects, edit the model and change the BF statement to 300 (for the MPS8050 at least).

Comment: but these are datasheets. i need the spice files to integrate in LTspice. How can I create it from these info?

Comment: Huh??? You look at the list of equivalents and choose one which is  in LTspice's library, then run the sim with that one.

Comment: is there a list of equivalents? where is that?